# Connecting Raspberry Pi3 to L9110S H-Bridge

Tags: pi-3

What is the best way to connect a Raspberry Pi3 to a L9110S H-Bridge Dual DC Stepper Motor Controller ?

Will be driving a "17HS4401 4 Lead NEMA 17" Stepper Motor with this unit.

Any help with which IO Pins to use for communication and power would be helpful.

[image]

Also, will it work with the stepper motor python library ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The L9110S can't supply a great deal of current (less than an amp per channel).  I assume you have checked it can drive your stepper.

Use any GPIO you want for the L9110S inputs.

You will need to connect a Pi ground to the power supply you will use for the stepper driver.  If you will be using the Pi 5V supply then just connect a 5V pin to Vcc of the L9110S.

Which Python stepper library are you planning to use?

---

EDITED TO ADD

As I say which GPIO you use is fairly arbitrary.  You can use any you are not using for another purpose.

As it happens I have 5 (4-phase) steppers using ULN2003A as drivers set up on a Pi B+.

I am using the following GPIO

```
   s1: 17, 15, 14,  4
   s2: 18, 27, 22, 23
   s3: 25,  9, 10, 24
   s4: 21, 20, 26, 16
   s5:  6, 12, 13, 19
```

I chose those as they are grouped together on the expansion header.

Connect your 12V+ to Vcc, 12V- to Ground, and also connect the 12V- (power supply ground) to a Pi ground.

Connect your chosen 4 GPIO to the A1, A2, B1, B2 pins of the L9110S.

I don't think there is a standard Python stepper library. Google will find lots of examples.  Choose one at random and if you get stuck post a new question.

Comment: I will be using an external 12V to power the motor. Just want to know the configuration for connecting the controller and PI. Ignore the library part, still reading on it. Any that you suggest ?

Comment: @amyth91 I have edited the answer to add information.

Answer (score 0):

What @joan said. Also, even at <1A/ch, the pi can't supply that kind of current. Always use a separate power supply to drive stepper motors and servos (I do!), and don't forget (as @joan said) to connect the grounds.