# I'm trying to control two 12V DC motors with a RPi 2 using a L9110S H Bridge, but can't make it work

Tags: pi-2

I already followed the steps listed in this answer: [Connecting Raspberry Pi3 to L9110S H-Bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/46633/connecting-raspberry-pi3-to-l9110s-h-bridge)

But it seems I must be doing something wrong because it still doesn't work.

I have a 12V battery 4800mAh (http://es.aliexpress.com/item/Free-Ship-Lipo-Battery-Portable-4800mAh-DC-12V-12-6V-Super-Rechargeable-Pack-EU-US-plug/32584864714.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.93.A2l9Zd)

These 12V motors: http://es.aliexpress.com/item/ROT-1-New-tracked-vehicle-chassis-metal-buggy-robot-tanks-video-show/32278263918.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.61.A2l9Zd

And this H bridge: http://es.aliexpress.com/item/Smart-Electronics-5Pcs-lot-L9110S-DC-Stepper-Motor-Driver-Board-H-Bridge-best-prices/32512498164.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.69.DbnLzz

I connected the battery to the H bridge using a power jack, then the battery to the raspberry pi ground, then the h bridge to the raspberry gpio ports and the H bridge to the motors.

I'm using GPIO 23 and 24, using the gpio command line utility, but nothing works.

Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you using Broadcom GPIO numbers or pin numbers or wiringPi numbers?  By default I think the gpio utility uses wiringPi numbers.

Comment: @joan Yes, wiring Pi

Comment: wPi 23 is pin 33 (GPIO13). wPi 24 is pin 35 (GPIO19).  Are they the GPIO you have connected to your motor driver board?

Comment: @joan Yes. I'm using these two: http://i.imgur.com/tTUtaYu.jpg

Comment: What commands are you using to set the GPIO as OUTPUTs and to set one high and the other low?

Comment: gpio mode 23 out, gpio mode 24 out, gpio write pin 1/0

Comment: @joan I mean: gpio write 23 0, gpio write 24 1, also tried viceversa

Comment: That should work, provided you have also connected a ground wire between the L9110S and the Pi.

Comment: Are you trying to control two motors with the two GPIO pins or just one motor. If both then you need to switch 4 GPIO pins.

Comment: One motor, for starters...

Comment: Have you verified the motor works by connecting it directly to the 12v?

Comment: Yes I did, and they work.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. The problem was: I was connecting the raspberry ground pin to the power jack ground pin. I connected it instead to the ground pin of the **H bridge**. It works now.
Thanks everybody